# How can I use arrays to ask my customers the quantity they want and print a receipt from the arrays?

Tags: c++, arrays

I need to create arrays that save the quantity of the item the user selects and also prints out a receipt with the product, quantity and the total price. Please help me understand how to do this. I've got a basic understanding of what an array is. I just couldn't figure out how to save the users input.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <Windows.h>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <string>
#include "customerclass.h"
using namespace std;


//***** Functions to calculate the price of multiple items *****
void finalPrice1(int itemQuantity) {
    float price;
    price = itemQuantity * 3.00;
    cout << "Your total is $" << price << endl;
    cout << "Thank you for using my shop" << endl;
    exit(0);
}
void finalPrice2(int itemQuantity) {
    float price;
    price = itemQuantity * 2.50;
    cout << "Your total is $" << price << endl;
    cout << "Thank you for using my shop" << endl;
    exit(0);
}
void finalPrice3(int itemQuantity) {
    float price;
    price = itemQuantity * 1.25;
    cout << "Your total is $" << price << endl;
    cout << "Thank you for using my shop" << endl;
    exit(0);
}   //***** End of functions that calculate price of multiple items *****




int main(void)
{
    char selection = ' ';
    string lname = "";
    string luserAddress;
    int itemQuantity;
    string orderFinalized;
    CustomerInfo myCustomerInfo;

    do
    {  // Displaying menu
        cout << "Hello, welcome to my online shop! What is your name? " << endl;
        cin >> lname;
        cout << " And what is your shipping address? " << endl;
        cin >> luserAddress;
        myCustomerInfo.setName(lname);
        myCustomerInfo.setAddress(luserAddress);

        cout <<  lname + ", nice to meet you. Here are the items in my shop followed by the price, please enter the number that corresponds to the item you want. \n " << endl;



        cout << "Products \n";
        cout << "1 - Chocolate candy bar - $3.00" << endl;
        cout << "2 - Sour hard candy - $2.50" << endl;
        cout << "3 - Mints - $1.25" << endl;
        cout << "4 - Exit" << endl << endl;
        cout << "Enter selection ";
        // Reading User Selection
        cin >> selection;
        switch (selection)
        {
        case '1':
            cout << "You've chosen a Chocolate candy bar. How many would you like? ";
            cin >> itemQuantity;
            cout << "Ok, will this finalize your order? Type and enter either 'Yes' or 'No' " << endl;
            cin >> orderFinalized;
            if (orderFinalized == "Yes" || orderFinalized == "yes" || orderFinalized == "YES") {
                cout << myCustomerInfo.getName() + " your items will be shipped to " << myCustomerInfo.getAddress() << endl;
                cout << "Printing your receipt now..." << endl;
                finalPrice1(itemQuantity);
            }
            break;
        case '2':
            cout << "You've chosen Sour hard candy. How many would you like? ";
            cin >> itemQuantity;
            cout << "Ok, will this finalize your order? Type and enter either 'Yes' or 'No' " << endl;
            cin >> orderFinalized;
            if (orderFinalized == "Yes" || orderFinalized == "yes" || orderFinalized == "YES") {
                cout << myCustomerInfo.getName() + " your items will be shipped to " << myCustomerInfo.getAddress() << endl;
                cout << "Printing your receipt now..." << endl;
                finalPrice2(itemQuantity);
            }
            break;
        case '3':
            cout << "You've chosen Mints. How many would you like? ";
            cin >> itemQuantity;
            cout << "Ok, will this finalize your order? Type and enter either 'Yes' or 'No' " << endl;
            cin >> orderFinalized;
            if (orderFinalized == "Yes" || "yes" || "YES") {
                cout << myCustomerInfo.getName() + " your items will be shipped to " << myCustomerInfo.getAddress() << endl;
                cout << "Printing your receipt now..." << endl;
                finalPrice3(itemQuantity);

            }
            break;
        case '4':
            cout << "Thank you for using my shop. <exiting now...>" << endl;
            break;

        default: cout << "Invalid selection. Please try again";
        }
        cout << endl << endl;
    } while (selection != '4');
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Use a `std::vector` of the object that represents each item in the order.

Answer (score 0):

You need dynamic array. For example:

```
cin >> itemQuantity;
// create a array during runtime
// and the size is itemQuantity
// you can access the ith array element by items[i]
Item *items= new Item[itemQuantity];
```

Or you can use the [vector](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/),

```
vector<Item> items;//you can also access the ith element by items[i]
items.push_back(hard_candy);//items = {hard_candy}
items.push_back(soft_candy);//items = {hard_candy, soft_candy}
items.pop_back();//items = {hard_candy}
```

BTW, the case 3 in your code has some error:

```
orderFinalized == "Yes" || "yes" || "YES"//wrong
orderFinalized == "Yes" || orderFinalized == "yes" || orderFinalized == "YES"//right
```